# raraise IOError( OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /home/marc/Documents/Drowsiness+Road Pathole/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have created a haar cascade model using tensorflow , which detects wheather driver is drowsy or not. after executing the code I get an error which states

> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/marc/Documents/Drowsiness+Road
> Pathole/Drowsiness_Detection1.py", line 215, in Drowsiness
> model = load_model('/home/marc/Documents/Drowsiness+Road Pathole')
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "/home/marc/anaconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/saving/saving_api.py",
> line 212, in load_model
> return legacy_sm_saving_lib.load_model(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/marc/anaconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py",
> line 70, in error_handler
> raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None   File "/home/marc/anaconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py",
> line 116, in parse_saved_model
> raise IOError( OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /home/marc/Documents/Drowsiness+Road
> Pathole/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
> I think so the reason behind this error is the older version of tensorflow is used in the code and I am executing it using latest version. If that'so please help me in updating the code

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image , ImageTk
from gtts import gTTS
import os

root = tk.Toplevel()
w , h = root.winfo_screenwidth() , root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0"%(w,h))
img = Image.open("bg.jpg")
img =img.resize((w,h), Image.ANTIALIAS)

background_image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image)

background_label.image = background_image

background_label.place(x=0, y=0) #, relwidth=1, relheight=1)




def Drowsiness():
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import time
    import sys

    path = "classifiers/haar-face.xml"
    faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(path)

    # Variable used to hold the ratio of the contour area to the ROI
    ratio = 0

    # variable used to hold the average time duration of the yawn
    global yawnStartTime
    yawnStartTime = 0

    # Flag for testing the start time of the yawn
    global isFirstTime
    isFirstTime = True

    # List to hold yawn ratio count and timestamp
    global yawnRatioCount
    yawnRatioCount = []

    # Yawn Counter
    yawnCounter = 0

    # yawn time
    averageYawnTime = 2.5

    """
    Find the second largest contour in the ROI; 
    Largest is the contour of the bottom half of the face.
    Second largest is the lips and mouth when yawning.
    """

    def calculateContours(image, contours):
        cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
        maxArea = 0
        secondMax = 0
        maxCount = 0
        secondmaxCount = 0
        for i in contours:
            count = i
            area = cv2.contourArea(count)
            if maxArea < area:
                secondMax = maxArea
                maxArea = area
                secondmaxCount = maxCount
                maxCount = count
            elif (secondMax < area):
                secondMax = area
                secondmaxCount = count

        return [secondmaxCount, secondMax]

    """
    Thresholds the image and converts it to binary
    """

    def thresholdContours(mouthRegion, rectArea):
        global ratio

        # Histogram equalize the image after converting the image from one color space to another
        # Here, converted to greyscale
        imgray = cv2.equalizeHist(cv2.cvtColor(mouthRegion, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))

        # Thresholding the image => outputs a binary image.
        # Convert each pixel to 255 if that pixel each exceeds 64. Else convert it to 0.
        ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray, 64, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

        # Finds contours in a binary image
        # Constructs a tree like structure to hold the contours
        # Contouring is done by having the contoured region made by of small rectangles and storing only the end points
        # of the rectangle
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        returnValue = calculateContours(mouthRegion, contours)

        # returnValue[0] => secondMaxCount
        # returnValue[1] => Area of the contoured region.
        secondMaxCount = returnValue[0]
        contourArea = returnValue[1]

        ratio = contourArea / rectArea

        # Draw contours in the image passed. The contours are stored as vectors in the array.
        # -1 indicates the thickness of the contours. Change if needed.
        if (isinstance(secondMaxCount, np.ndarray) and len(secondMaxCount) > 0):
            cv2.drawContours(mouthRegion, [secondMaxCount], 0, (255, 0, 0), -1)

    """
    Isolates the region of interest and detects if a yawn has occured. 
    """

    def yawnDetector(video_capture):
        global ratio, yawnStartTime, isFirstTime, yawnRatioCount, yawnCounter
        yawnCounter = 0
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()

        gray = cv2.equalizeHist(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))
        gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.1,
            minNeighbors=5,
            minSize=(50, 50),
            # flags=cv2.cv2.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
            flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
        )

        # Draw a rectangle around the faces
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

            # Isolate the ROI as the mouth region
            widthOneCorner = int((x + (w / 4)))
            widthOtherCorner = x + int(((3 * w) / 4))
            heightOneCorner = y + int((11 * h / 16))
            heightOtherCorner = y + h

            # Indicate the region of interest as the mouth by highlighting it in the window.
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (widthOneCorner, heightOneCorner), (widthOtherCorner, heightOtherCorner), (0, 255, 0),
                          2)
            # cv2.circle(img, center, radius, (0, 255, 0), 2)

            # mouth region
            mouthRegion = frame[heightOneCorner:heightOtherCorner, widthOneCorner:widthOtherCorner]

            # Area of the bottom half of the face rectangle
            rectArea = (w * h) / 2

            if (len(mouthRegion) > 0):
                thresholdContours(mouthRegion, rectArea)

            print("Current probablity of yawn: " + str(round(ratio * 1000, 2)) + "%")
            print("Length of yawnCounter: " + str(len(yawnRatioCount)))

            if (ratio > 0.06):
                if (isFirstTime is True):
                    isFirstTime = False
                    yawnStartTime = time.time()

                # If the mouth is open for more than 2.5 seconds, classify it as a yawn
                if ((time.time() - yawnStartTime) >= averageYawnTime):
                    yawnCounter += 1
                    yawnRatioCount.append(yawnCounter)

                    if (len(yawnRatioCount) > 8):
                        # Reset all variables
                        isFirstTime = True
                        yawnStartTime = 0
                        return True

        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.namedWindow('yawnVideo')
        cv2.imshow('yawnVideo', frame)
        time.sleep(0.025)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            sys.exit(0)

        return False

    """
    Main
    """

    # Capture from web camera
    # yawnCamera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    import cv2
    import os
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
    import numpy as np
    from pygame import mixer
    import time


    mixer.init()
    sound = mixer.Sound('alarm.wav')

    face = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haar cascade files/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
    leye = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haar cascade files/haarcascade_lefteye_2splits.xml')
    reye = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haar cascade files/haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml')



    lbl=['Close','Open']

    model = load_model('models/cnnCat2.h5')
    path = os.getcwd()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
    count=0
    score=0
    thicc=2
    rpred=[99]
    lpred=[99]
    #sound = mixer.Sound('alarm.wav')
    while(True):
        returnValue = (yawnDetector(cap), 'yawn')
        if returnValue[0]:
            print(returnValue)
            print("Yawn detected!")
            TTS = gTTS('Yawn detected')
            TTS.save('Yawn.mp3')
            os.system('Yawn.mp3')
            sound.play()
            # When everything is done, release the capture
            # yawnCamera.release()
            #cv2.destroyWindow('yawnVideo')
            #return returnValue
        else:
            sound.stop()




        ret, frame = cap.read()
        height,width = frame.shape[:2]

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        faces = face.detectMultiScale(gray,minNeighbors=5,scaleFactor=1.1,minSize=(25,25))
        left_eye = leye.detectMultiScale(gray)
        right_eye =  reye.detectMultiScale(gray)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (0,height-50) , (200,height) , (0,0,0) , thickness=cv2.FILLED )

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y) , (x+w,y+h) , (100,100,100) , 1 )

        for (x,y,w,h) in right_eye:
            r_eye=frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
            count=count+1
            r_eye = cv2.cvtColor(r_eye,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            r_eye = cv2.resize(r_eye,(24,24))
            r_eye= r_eye/255
            r_eye=  r_eye.reshape(24,24,-1)
            r_eye = np.expand_dims(r_eye,axis=0)
            rpred = model.predict_classes(r_eye)
            if(rpred[0]==1):
                lbl='Open'
            if(rpred[0]==0):
                lbl='Closed'
            break

        for (x,y,w,h) in left_eye:
            l_eye=frame[y:y+h,x:x+w]
            count=count+1
            l_eye = cv2.cvtColor(l_eye,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            l_eye = cv2.resize(l_eye,(24,24))
            l_eye= l_eye/255
            l_eye=l_eye.reshape(24,24,-1)
            l_eye = np.expand_dims(l_eye,axis=0)
            lpred = model.predict_classes(l_eye)
            if(lpred[0]==1):
                lbl='Open'
            if(lpred[0]==0):
                lbl='Closed'
            break

        if(rpred[0]==0 and lpred[0]==0):
            score=score+1
            cv2.putText(frame,"Closed",(10,height-20), font, 1,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
            print("Wake Up!!!")
            TTS = gTTS('Wake Up')
            TTS.save('wakeup.mp3')
            os.system('wakeup.mp3')
            
        # if(rpred[0]==1 or lpred[0]==1):
        else:
            score=0
            cv2.putText(frame,"Open",(10,height-20), font, 1,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
            print("Safe!")
            TTS = gTTS('U R Safe')
            TTS.save('safe.mp3')
            os.system('safe.mp3')
        if(score<0):
            score=0
        cv2.putText(frame,'Score:'+str(score),(100,height-20), font, 1,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
        if(score>5):
            #person is feeling sleepy so we beep the alarm
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path,'image.jpg'),frame)
            try:
                sound.play()

            except:  # isplaying = False
                pass
            if(thicc<16):
                thicc= thicc+2
            else:
                thicc=thicc-2
                if(thicc<2):
                    thicc=2
            cv2.rectangle(frame,(0,0),(width,height),(0,0,255),thicc)
        else:
            sound.stop()
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break



    #while True:
        #returnValue = (yawnDetector(cap), 'yawn')
        #if returnValue[0]:
            #print("Yawn detected!")
            # When everything is done, release the capture
            #yawnCamera.release()
           # cv2.destroyWindow('yawnVideo')
            #return returnValue

    #main()

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#Yawn()
#EDrowsiness()

def Exit():
    root.destroy()
    


button1 = tk.Button(root,text="Drowsiness", command= Drowsiness)
button1.place(x=100 , y=100)

button2 =tk.Button(root,text="Exit", command= Exit)
button2.place(x=100 , y=200)

root.mainloop()
```

Dependencies Installed in enviroment

```
conda list tensorflow
# packages in environment at /home/marc/anaconda3/envs/project:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
tensorflow                2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.32.0                   pypi_0    pypi
```

So,help me if you can I need it

Comment: Hi @Avdhut Joshi, Which tensorflow version have you used to save the model? Please check if the given path is correct to load the saved model. You can try giving full directory path to load the model.